# Scrapy: Scraping text embedded inside an href

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape content as follows:

```
>>> response.css(".mt-0.mb-2").extract()

['<h4 class="mt-0 mb-2">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="https://www.example.com/results/item1/">THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO SCRAPE</a>                    </h4>', '<h4 class="mt-0 mb-2">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=…
```

The problem is that when I try to get just the text, I am not getting the "THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO SCRAPE" string, but the tabs:

```
>>> response.css(".mt-0.mb-2::text").extract()

['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '                    ', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '                    ', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '                    ', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t',
```

When dealing with these type of selectors, are XPaths the only way to extract them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what is about `response.css(".mt-0.mb-2 a::text").extract()`? Or maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I'm getting only tabs and white spaces instead of the actual string 'THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO SCRAPE'.

Comment: Do you see that inside css expression we added `a`, and take it's text with `a::text`. Did you try it?

Comment: Apologies I did not see that! Thanks, this will help me understand a bit more how to deal with nested resources.